# How to sum the number of houses surveyed from the table CodeIgniter and MySql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Here's my  SQL question...

I have three tables:

course_subcategory

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| course_subcat_id | course_cat_id| subcoursename| code| 
-------------------------------------------------------
```

course_category

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| course_cat_id |  coursename| code| project  |deleted|
-------------------------------------------------------
```

events

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|event_id|title| project |course_cat_id |course_subcat_id|no_of_house_surveyed
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

-

I want to show the total number  of house surveyed and number of events occured 
having same course_cat_id and course_subcat_id.

Here is my code.

> models

```
function getCourseCat(){
        $this->db->select('COUNT(e.title) as no_of_events, SUM(e.no_of_house_surveyed) as total_house_surveyed, c.course_cat_id, c.coursename,s.course_subcat_id,
                  s.subcoursename' )
                  ->from('events e')
                  ->join('course_category c ON e.course_cat_id = c.course_cat_id')
                  ->join('course_subcategory s ON e.course_subcat_id = s.course_subcat_id')
                  ->group_by('e.event_id');
          $result=$this->db->get()->result();
          }
```

> controller

$data['course_cat'] = $this->test_event_summary_model->getCourseCat();`enter code here`

> views

```
foreach($course_cat->result() as $c){

                if ($c->no_of_events == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
echo "<td>".$c->no_of_events."</td>";

                $total_events += $c->no_of_events;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this answer will solve your problem-

> Model

```
function getCourseCat(){
    $where = "e.course_cat_id = c.course_cat_id AND e.course_subcat_id = s.course_subcat_id";
    $this->db->select('c.course_cat_id,c.coursename,s.course_subcat_id,s.subcoursename,COUNT(e.title) as no_of_events,SUM(e.no_of_house_surveyed) as total_house_surveyed');
    $this->db->from('events e');
    $this->db->from('course_category c');
    $this->db->from('course_subcategory s');
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->group_by(array("c.course_cat_id", "c.coursename", "s.course_subcat_id", "s.subcoursename"));
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $res = $query->result_array();
    return $res;
}
```

> Controller

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('test_event_summary_model');
    $res['results'] = $this->test_event_summary_model->getCourseCat();
    $this->load->view('cat_view',$res);
}
```

> View

```
foreach ($results as $res) {
    echo "<b>course_cat_id</b> - ".$res['course_cat_id']."<br>";
    echo "<b>coursename</b> - ".$res['coursename']."<br>";
    echo "<b>course_subcat_id</b> - ".$res['course_subcat_id']."<br>";
    echo "<b>subcoursename</b> - ".$res['subcoursename']."<br>";
    echo "<b>no_of_events</b> - ".$res['no_of_events']."<br>";
    echo "<b>total_house_surveyed</b> - ".$res['total_house_surveyed'];
}
```

> Output

[image: The output will be something like this-]

Comment: But how can i show all the courses name and subcourses name along with the no of events and no of house surveyed for each subcourse?

Comment: @palistha I have updated my answer. Please just change the model code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
function getCourseCat() {
    $this->db->select('COUNT(e.title) as no_of_events, SUM(e.no_of_house_surveyed) as total_house_surveyed, c.course_cat_id, c.coursename,s.course_subcat_id, s.subcoursename' )
      ->from('events as e')
      ->join('course_category as c', 'e.course_cat_id = c.course_cat_id')
      ->join('course_subcategory as s', 'e.course_subcat_id = s.course_subcat_id')
      ->group_by('e.event_id');
    $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

Hope this solve your problem.

Comment: When I try to display the value in view file, it returns Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object . Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getCourseCat() {
    $this->db->select('COUNT(e.title) as no_of_events, SUM(e.no_of_house_surveyed) as total_house_surveyed, c.course_cat_id, c.coursename,s.course_subcat_id, s.subcoursename' )
      ->from('events as e')
      ->join('course_category as c', 'e.course_cat_id = c.course_cat_id')
      ->join('course_subcategory as s', 'e.course_subcat_id = s.course_subcat_id')
      ->group_by('e.event_id');
        $result = $this->db->get();
        return $result;
}
```

Comment: why/how does this fix the original problem?

Comment: It returns Undefined property: mysqli::$no_of_events